# MySQL performance tuning - unique constraints

Tags: mysql

I have a database in MySQL 5.5. I eventually expect to have tens of millions of records in there.

If I add a unique constraint on two columns, I know there will be some performance penalty for inserts; the question is, how much? And what can I do to minimize it?

Would the penalty be different if instead I had the unique constraint on a *single* column?

Comment: Obviously it's not possible to answer to your question - you either need a constraint that helps you to maintain integrity, or not.

Comment: @zerkms - I won't go into too much detail, but in this case, there might be other things I can do to guarantee integrity. So I'm just trying to figure out if it's worth investigating those other options.

Comment: will you search by that columns pair?

Comment: then if as you said you have an alternative - I'd try to go with alternative. Index that won't be used for search looks redundant at first glance (but we don't know details of your task)

Answer (score 5):

The first penalty is space.  Index tables will be created in your db for them and with 10 million rows this isn't trivial, but may not be a big concern to you.  As @zerkms pointed out however, these indexes should be cached in memory buffers for the them to be fast, so you might have an issue there.

Two unique indexes should not slow your inserts down significantly vs. a single unique index.  The Unique constraint check is pretty cheap for Mysql to determine.  You won't see exponential slow down by adding indexes (unless you hit some memory issue), but more of a additional linear time increase for each new one you tack on.

Comment: Space (disk one) in 2013 isn't that big issue. What worse is that indexes need to be fit and kept in RAM to be really efficient.

Comment: Change a reference to me from "someone" and you'll get my upvote :-)

Comment: Hi, @Ray what would happen in situation we create an constrain key with lots of fields like constraint update_key unique (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, f11, f12, f13, f14, f15, f16, f17, f18, f19, f20)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739231/would-constraint-unique-key-with-lot-of-fields-hurt-mysql-performance

Comment: @igonejack I would think that as long as it's within the max limit for index size it would work, you might bust that with too many columns: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html.  If it's under the limit, the number of columns wouldn't change the fact it's a constant lookup